# Linking AWS domain name with the application server IP

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a problem on how to point my DNS registered through AWS to one of the servers that were associated with my EC2 IP.

For deploying my application, I created an EC2 IP in AWS and then installed shiny server and Rstudio so that I could deploy my app. So now I have an IP with the following linkage (I’m using MyIP instead of the IP number):

1. MyIP:3838 opens shiny server
2. MyIP:8787 opens Rstudio
3. MyIP:3838/My_app opens my application

Then I created a hosted zone from route 53 and linked my EC2 IP to my domain name. But when I write the domain name in the web address, it fails. I think this is because 3 servers as I described above were linked to MyIP (EC2 IP). My question is How I can point DNS to only the application web server? (for linking the DNS to EC2 IP I used this instruction: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/get-a-domain/). Do you have any idea on that? Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To clarify... Did you create an **Elastic IP Address**, or did you use the IP address automatically assigned to the EC2 instance? What type of record did you create in Route 53 - was it an `A`-Record? Did you _ONLY_ put the IP address in the `A`-Record, or did you put the port number, etc? Can you show us more of your configuration?

Comment: I used IPv4 Public IP which includes 9 numbers and when I launched instance, this IP was assigned to it. (when I type this IP followed by :3838/My_app in the web address browser, my app shows up). I created type A record and as a value I put only this IPv4 Public IP.

Comment: Have you tested whether the DNS name resolves to the correct IP address? You can use a service like https://dnschecker.org/ to check whether it is working. You should then be able to use `http://your-dns-name:3838/My_app` to access the application.

Comment: I've tested that. now I can get access to app by http://your-dns-name:3838/My_app but it is unusual to have 3838/My_app at the end of the domain name. I should have .com at the end like other websites. How could I get access to the app by only the domain name?

Comment: By default, web servers run on port 80 for HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS. If you want to people to access your application by only using a domain name, you'll need to either change the port for your app, or run a web server on port 80/443 that can redirect users.

Comment: Would you please let me know how I could do this? This is not my field so if you could send me some instructions on this I would be do thankful to you.

Comment: This is not a programming topic. You might want to ask a Question on https://serverfault.com/